# What happens to the Fermi level of a metal when a dc electric field is applied?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, metals, non-equilibrium, chemical-potential

For metals, the Fermi level $E_F$, which is also equal to the chemical potential $\mu$ at absolute zero of temperature, is the highest occupied energy level at $T=0$. In terms of the electron number density $n$, it has the familiar expression $E_F=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e}(3\pi^2n)^{2/3}$ which is derived using the equilibrium Fermi-Dirac distribution $$f_i=\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{E_i-\mu(T)}{kT}\right)-1}$$ I want to know what happens to the Fermi level, again at $T=0$, but with an applied dc electric field. Does the Fermi energy, defined as $E_F=\mu(T=0)$, move up or down?

Please note that I am using the definition of Fermi energy as the chemical potential at $T=0$, and does not have any temperature dependence. I am asking: Does the zero-field Fermi energy $E_F(T=0,{\vec E}=0)$ differ from the Fermi energy with nonzero fields $E_F(T=0,{\vec E}\neq 0)$ and if so, by what amount? Thanks. I am in doubt because once an electric field is applied the system is not in equilibrium anymore.